# How can I automatically read out data from interactive chart into a table?

Tags: image-processing, web-scraping, interactive

Recently more and more interactive charts show up on the Net. Have a look at the following one:

http://www.finanzen.net/zertifikate/zertifikate_emittenten_detail.asp?inEmNr=47

**My question**
Is there a possibility of automatically reading out the data into a table? Are there some tools available because I can't find the data in the source code? There should be a solution because if you point to the curve you'll get all the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if u use linux u can use the tool `[espeak][1]`. This is a command line tool which expects plain text as input and it will read it out load. So if you can some how arrange for the data to be plain text is it possible.